# Is there any element on exist / load in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click a button, I'm adding a paragraph with a `p` tag. My jQuery is as follows:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('body').append('< p>Hello World !< /p>');
})
```

So, when the page loads, the `p` tag isn't present in the html page, so JavaScript won't recognize the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     // or window.ready(function
    $('p').after('<span>abcd</span>')
}
```

In CSS - the properties applies to the specified elements regardless whether the element exists or not. Similarly I want to do the same with jQuery.

Comment: Are you wanting to run `$('p').after('<span>abcd</span>')` after it is added to the DOM?

Comment: use `after` after you append `p`

Comment: Do you mean to get callback once "P" element is added to the DOM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use **Mutation Observer**.

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

function callback (mutations) {
  // do something here
}

observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     // or window.ready(function
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('p')) {
            $(e.target).after('<span>abcd</span>');
        }
    })

})
```

This will add `<span>abcd</span>` every time a `p` tag is added to the DOM

Comment: yup exactly ,,,,, DOMNodeInserted was what i was looking for. Thanks.

BUT THE CODE DID NOT WORK..

https://jsitor.com/wETDHeSVC

Comment: @SrinivasanD Sorry, I was missing a closing paren, it should work now.

Comment: Is there anything like DOMnode where it can check/listen element style and act?
Example...an element style display block is set then later if display is set to flex something should happen !!!   @CummingUp07